# What is the difference between "Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll" and "Task.WhenAll().ContinueWith"?

Tags: c#, task

I have understood the difference between "task.Start ()", "Task.Run()", "Task.Factory.StartNew" after searching through google (the latter two should be mainly used), but "Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll" and "Task.WhenAll().ContinueWith", I found that I should mainly use the latter. Why?

Does the method derived from "Task.Factory" have an optimization effect?

Comment: Well, look at the official documentation of both of them, and pay attention to what each of them passes to the continuation. That said, normally or "mainly" you wouldn't use either of them, and instead you would just use `await Task.WhenAll(...)`.

Comment: *"...I found that I should mainly use the latter."* -- Where did you find that you should use the later? Could you edit the question and include the link?

Comment: I am more interested in knowing what is hidden behind "Task.  Factory" than I am in knowing which one to use.
Also about "...I found that I should mainly use the latter.", it is from this article "https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html" which says "TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll: And I recommend not using these overloads at all, either; instead, use await Task.WhenAll(...)" The passage.